# Different ApplicationType depending on Configuration and Platform in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, configuration, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to configure a library project in Visual Studio 2017 in such a way that it changes its entire `ApplicationType` depending on the `$(Configuration)|$(Platform)` condition. In particular, I'd like to create a configuration which allows to build the same library project for both, Windows and Android.

Here's what I've tried:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{602F842F-50C1-466D-8696-1707937D8AB9}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>MyNamespace</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <VCProjectVersion>15.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17134.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM64'" Label="Configuration">
    <Keyword>Android</Keyword>
    <ApplicationType>Android</ApplicationType>
    <ApplicationTypeRevision>3.0</ApplicationTypeRevision>
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>Clang_5_0</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However, it treats the Android-configuration as if it were a Windows-library. I guess, Visual Studio takes the application type of the first project and applies it to all other configuration+platform combinations. If I define the application type "Android" in the "Globals" section like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{602F842F-50C1-466D-8696-1707937D8AB9}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>MyNamespace</RootNamespace>
    <Keyword>Android</Keyword>
    <ApplicationType>Android</ApplicationType>
    <ApplicationTypeRevision>3.0</ApplicationTypeRevision>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

then Visual Studio applies the Android-library type to all configuration+platform combinations. That's the expected behavior. But it seems to be impossible to define the application type per configuration+platform combination. Can it be done or am I out of luck?

Comment: Simple way would be common library project and 2 application projects that use the common library project.  There would be minimal code in the application projects (only platform/target specific code).

Comment: Wanted to avoid too many projects in my solution, but I'll try that. Thanks.